# How to set Node-adodb timezone to retrieve datetime in correct time zone

Tags: sql, node.js, electron, adodb

I am using node-adodb in my electron app. I query mdb file but i get datetime in wrong timezone. How can i set timezone or Do i query using wrong method.

My date format in mdb file

- USERID    CHECKTIME
- 421   2/11/2019 11:54:19 AM
- 433   2/11/2019 11:54:18 AM
- 431   2/11/2019 11:54:17 AM

I am using node-adodb with electron
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-adodb

I want to retrieve checktime and badgenumber from mdb file using lastupdatetime and save it in another table with lastupdatetime. After trying hard i am able to retrieve datetime from mdb file . Here is my code

```
var connection = this.adoDb.open('Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\\SIMS\\bio_att\\att2000.mdb');
let ab = '2019/02/11:11:10:00';
connection
.query("SELECT CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,USERINFO.Badgenumber FROM CHECKINOUT INNER JOIN USERINFO ON CHECKINOUT.USERID = USERINFO.USERID WHERE format(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,'yyyy/mm/dd:HH:mm:ss') >=  '"+ab+"'")
.then(data => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

When i query datetime it returns correct data but in wrong timezone. Is there any way to get correct timezone?
return data is correct
but timezone is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I changed

"SELECT CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME"

to

"SELECT format(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,'yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss')"

and now it returns date in correct timezone.
I hope its helpful if someone is looking for that

```
let ab = '2019/02/11 11:10:00';
connection
.query("SELECT format(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,'yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss') ,USERINFO.Badgenumber     FROM CHECKINOUT INNER JOIN USERINFO ON CHECKINOUT.USERID = USERINFO.USERID WHERE         format(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,'yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss') >=  '"+ab+"'")
.then(data => {
    this.dData = data;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    this.ldsRllrDisplay = 'none';
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```